# Creating multipart polygon using ArcObjects if coordinates of each part are given?

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, vba, multipart

How to create a multipart polygon if i am having the values of coordinates of each part.

I am using ArcObjects in VBA or VB.NET

Comment: using ArcObjects?

Comment: yes sir plz give me any code help in VBA or Vb.net.

Answer (score 3):

See the examples in the [ArcObjects conceptual help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/):

- [How to create a Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/index.html#//0001000002wm000000)
- [How to build a polygon using segments and points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/index.html#/How_to_build_a_polygon_using_segments_and_points/0001000002sq000000/)
- [How to create a union of several polygons](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/index.html#//00010000009t000000)